# Is there any creature like Warframe's desert skate in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, monster-design

WoTC has been known to use existing creatures and “skin” them for use as other creatures. (i.e. "DDAL06-02 The Redemption of Kelvan" contained a clockwork wyvern construct that had stats based on a regular wyvern and Tomb of Annihilation had clay warriors based on NPC gladiators.)

Is there any creature that resembles Warframe's **desert skate** or that could easily be skinned as one?

Images: http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Desert_Skate

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHRGVjev32g

We would be looking for a creature with three functions: a poison tail, dig movement and an elevated challenge rating > 1.

As a clarification: we are not looking for a creature that looks like a skate - but rather, similar to how WotC skins their creature, find a creature that has the same fundamental skills as listed above.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to a Monster Manual?

Comment: This was probably put on hold as we are unsure whether you want a creature that is mechanically similar, similar in appearance, or just similar in function. Please clarify

Comment: @Jason_c_o We have looked. We are wondering if there is anything in other books or official WotC adventures that might fit or missed something.

Comment: Are you really okay with any CR > 1?

Comment: @Miniman the higher the better

Answer (score 6):

### The Purple Worm

MM 255 has the Purple Worm. It's CR 15, and has the following abilities:

> **Tunneler.** The worm can burrow through solid rock at half its burrow speed and leaves a 10-foot-diameter tunnel in its wake.
>
> **Tail Stinger.** Melee Weapon Attack: +9 to hit, reach 10ft., one creature. Hit: 19 (3d6 + 9) piercing damage, and the target must make a DC 19 Constitution saving throw, taking 42 (12d6) poison damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

That seems to fit all three of your criteria.

Comment: And native to the desert too...great one!

Comment: Just noticed the Purple Wormling is a CR2 possibility as well. https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=Purple+worm&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=